# How to say it grammatically correct "what food by what animals will be obtained"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I got some food and some animals.
And everyday I give them some food.

So, I decide what food will be eaten by what animal.

How to say it grammatically correct "**what food by what animals is obtained**"?

"is obtained" here is a passive voice, because this act can be daily repeated in context.

Comment: You should add more detail and context, and information on why you think this is (or isn't) correct, or you risk having your question closed.

Comment: LMS, tried to do it.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not following SVO (subject - verb - object/predicate) format?

Comment: @user3169, am I right with the following:
what food is obtained by what animals

Comment: But it's still not clear.  Are you trying to form a question, or a statement?  Is it part of a longer sentence, or should it stand on its own?

Comment: @stangdon, it is a statement and stands on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are pet sitting for a friend, you would ask:

> What animal gets what food?

That should prompt the pet parent to show/tell you which food to feed to each animal and how to feed them.

This is a very informal way of speaking.  If you want to formalize it some, you could say:

> Please show me which food is fed to each animal.

Comment: Thanx, 2nd variant works for me.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "feed" to "fed" in the last sentence - I assume it was just a typo.

Comment: Or "what animals receive what food?" and "show me which food is given to each animal".  There are many possible variations.